# Get the maximum addressable memory space on a Win32 system

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, ram, virtual-memory

Is there a way on Win32 systems to programmatically get the full size of the OS's addressable memory space, using the Win32 API (or any accessible DLL that would be installed on a >=XP system).  I know about `GetPerformanceInfo` and `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`, but the former only seems to deal with physical memory, and the latter pertains to memory addressable *by my program, not the OS*; since my program must be x86 and might be run on an x64 system, there is no guarantee this will even be ballpark.

Note: I'd prefer, but don't need, an exact size. I just need a "really good guess."

Comment: Is "2 GB" a good enough guess?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Nope. I don't really care what _I_ can address, I care what the _system_ can address. (Trust me, there is a use case for this, it's just really complicated.)

Comment: Oh I see, I misread!  Any hint at what the use-case is?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Carving the memory to disk ... sort of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc300158(v=vs.85).aspx) can get the physical limit.
- [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can retrieve the highest user virtual address the system can access.

Do either of those satisfy your requirement?

Comment: `GetNativeSystemInfo` sounds just like what I'm looking for.

Comment: It reports a number just under 8TB on my 64-bit system.

Comment: Well crud. I'm accepting for the time being because that _should_ get what I want.

Comment: 8TB is correct for Windows 8 and below. For 8.1, the maximum user mode address is 128TB.

Comment: @RaymondChen, not for 32 bit Windows which this question relates to.  Although it is ambiguous because Win32 is often used as the API name even on Win64, and the OP refers to both "Win32 system" and "Win32 API".   For 32 bit WIndows 4GB split 2GB user, and 2GB system space by default, but configurable for 3GB user/1GB system https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces

Comment: @Clifford "Win32" is the name of the subsystem and corresponding API. It does not imply any particular architecture.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't disagree, although would personally use the term Windows API if I were intending to be architecture agnostic.  Just noted for completeness although it might now be increasingly rare to be using 32 bit Windows, or building 32-bit applications.  The term Win32 was to distinguish the API from the entirely obsolete Win16, but the API itself is largely unchanged for 64 bit.

Comment: @Clifford OP says "...might be run on an x64 system" so OP considers x64 to be part of Win32. They want to find the highest user-mode address for a process running on the native architecture.

Comment: @RaymondChen. Point taken, but in fact says x86 on x64, so a 32- bit application running in the 32-bit subsystem of a 64 bit system.  Is that the point you were making, that it reports the address space if the platform not the application?

Comment: @Clifford My interpretation is that the OP wants to know "What is the maximum available virtual address the OS itself can access (even if my own process is not running natively, which it won't be if I'm an x86 process running on x64)."